# Prevent EditText from scrolling to cursor

Tags: android

Is it possible to keep EditText scrolled all the way to the left, instead of following the cursor while typing?

EditText is set to `WRAP_CONTENT` and text is longer than the view.

I have tried `post`ing a `scrollTo(0, 0)` in `afterTextChanged`, but it only works when `gravity` is `left` (text disappears if gravity is right or center).

Also, the scrolling (jump) is noticeable after each keystroke.
What would be a proper way to achieve this?

Update:
I managed to determine the first character of the longest line in TextView and `post` `bringPointIntoView(x)` in `onPreDrawListener` but the jump is still noticeable.

Comment: when you set gravity to right or center then cordinate will be changed to other so you must scrollTo(new_x, 0)  with new_x = yourc calculate result

Comment: I have updated the question. EditText is set to `WRAP_CONTENT` and text is longer than the EditText. Which means that even when I scroll to (0, 0) and gravity is `right`, at least some text should be visible (but it is not).